# Dispatched actions reach the action creator but not the receiver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My `toolbar` component dispatches an action `abortGame()`. I see in the console that it reaches the action creator (text "ONE!" displayed on the console) but never the reducer (text "TWO!" never displayed).

What is wrong?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './App';
import reducer from './store/reducers/reducer';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

const app = (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**reducer.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    score: 0
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.ABORT_GAME:
            console.log('TWO');
            return {
                ...state,
                score: 0,
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

**actionTypes.js**

```
export const ABORT_GAME = 'ABORT_GAME';
```

**actions.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const abortGame = () => {
    console.log('ONE!');
    return {
        type: actionTypes.ABORT_GAME
    };
};
```

**Toolbar.js (component)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { abortGame } from '../../store/actions/actions';
    
const toolbar = (props) => (
        <div>
            <div onClick={props.onAbortGame}><Link to="/">MyApp</Link></div>
        </div>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAbortGame: () => dispatch(abortGame)
    };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just missed the function brackets while dispatching the action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAbortGame: () => dispatch(abortGame)
    };
};
```

Just change this line `onAbortGame: () => dispatch(abortGame)` to `onAbortGame: () => dispatch(abortGame())`

`abortGame` is a action creator which is basically a function. So you need to call the function inside dispatch

Answer (score 0):

You just passing the function name in dispatch not calling it exactly.
Just convert the dispatch(abortGame())

[sandbox working link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-redux-qnmbk)